# Automatic commit tagging on pubspec.yaml version change for Flutter

Tags: git, flutter, version-control, tags

For some time now I've been using tags on commits for my Flutter projects.

All I'm doing is adding tag manualy in `Git/Log` tab in Android Studio by right clicking new commit. I believe there must be an easy way to automate this, perhaps by writing some plugin that would run on commit that would open `pubspec.yaml` and read `version` key from it. If not plugin, basic script and running it every time (even manualy) should be able to do that as well.

My question is simple: Is there any solution to this problem already? Is there any tool that will help me achieve my goal without spending time on writing mentioned above plugin?

Answer (score 1):

It look's like you might just be a bit annoyed to use Android Studio to create the tag. I would recommend you:

### Use the git command (`git tag`)

For example, `git tag v.1.2.3`.

To automate the version bumps for a new release, it looks like [cider](https://pub.dev/packages/cider). If you use `cider`, apparently you can use: `git tag $(cider version)`

### If you still want to automate it:

You have to parse the [pubspec](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec) `version` field, and set e.g. `version=$(getVersionFromPubspec)`.

Then use this variable in `git tag $version`.